# Prefix not adding proper position in XML serialization and namespace prefix

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces

I have converted below xml to c# class .

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateStatusByShipperRefNo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <HandlingStation>string</HandlingStation>
      <HAWB>int</HAWB>
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <StatusCode>string</StatusCode>
      <ShipperRefNo>string</ShipperRefNo>
    </UpdateStatusByShipperRefNo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Convert C# class as below for the xml

```
public class UpdateStatus
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "UpdateStatusByShipperRefNo", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public class UpdateStatusByShipperRefNo
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "HandlingStation", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public string HandlingStation { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "HAWB", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public string HAWB { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UserName", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "StatusCode", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public string StatusCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ShipperRefNo", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public string ShipperRefNo { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UpdateStatusByShipperRefNo", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public UpdateStatusByShipperRefNo UpdateStatusByShipperRefNo { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsd { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soap", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Soap { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my code i am trying to pass the value for each node. The value i have passed is on correct position but these line not format correctly from my code

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
```

the above line is convert in my xml like below

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP:Body>
```

i am using below code

```
var en = new ShipperRef.Envelope();
            en = new ShipperRef.Envelope
            {
                Body = new ShipperRef.Body
                {
                    UpdateStatusByShipperRefNo = new ShipperRef.UpdateStatusByShipperRefNo
                    {
                        HandlingStation = row["LocationName"].ToString(),
                        HAWB = row["REF"].ToString(),
                        UserName = row["DRV1NUM"].ToString(),
                        StatusCode = type,
                        ShipperRefNo = row["BILLGRP"].ToString()
                    }
                }
            };
            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("SOAP", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            try
            {
                var ser1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ShipperRef.Envelope));
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ser1.Serialize(ms, en);
                    using (var wc = new WebClient())
                    {
                        wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;                       
                        ms.Position = 0;
                        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(ms);
                        string requestString = stream.ReadToEnd();
                        var resp = wc.UploadData(EsteShipperUrl, ms.ToArray());
                        return (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resp));
                    }
                }
            }
```

can you please help me how to place namespace properly for this xml